# ¿Como tomar una funcion ingresada en una caja de texto como una expresion matematica en python?

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, sympy

Estoy realizando un programa en Python donde a través de una caja de texto recibo una "función", que en realidad vendría siendo un string, lo que pasa es que quiero tomar ese string y convertirlo a una función o expresión matemática como tal pero he tenido problemas a la hora de parsear el string. Por ejemplo, supongamos que el usuario ingresa lo siguiente: "x**2+3" junto con otros valores de tipo int, a lo que voy es que debo convertir esa expresion en una funcion y reemplazar en la x los otros valores entero ingresados. Aquí esta el codigo de la funcion donde tengo problemas:

```
def calcular():
# Obtener los valores de entrada del usuario
    a = DoubleVar()
    c = DoubleVar()
    funcion = StringVar()
    tolerancia = DoubleVar()
    
    funcion = funcion.get()
    a = a.get()
    c = c.get()
    tolerancia = tolerancia.get()
            # Limpiar la tabla antes de agregar los resultados
    for row in table.get_children():
        table.delete(row)

    # Configurar la función
    x = Symbol('x')
    transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))
    funcion = parse_expr(funcion, transformations=transformations)

    # Calcular los valores iniciales de la iteración
    b = (a + c) / 2
    fa = funcion.subs(x, a)
    fb = funcion.subs(x, b)
    fc = funcion.subs(x, c)
    error = tolerancia + 1
    iteracion = 1

    # Agregar la primera fila a la tabla
    table.insert('', 'end', values=(iteracion, round(a, 6), round(b, 6), round(c, 6), round(float(fa), 6), round(float(fb), 6), round(float(fc), 6), "-"))

    # Iterar hasta que se alcance la tolerancia o el número máximo de iteraciones
    while error > tolerancia:
        iteracion += 1
        if fa*fb > 0:
            a = b
            fa = fb
        else:
            c = b
            fc = fb

        b = (a + c) / 2
        fb = f.subs(x, b)
        error = abs((b - a) / b) * 100

        # Agregar la fila a la tabla
        table.insert('', 'end', values=(iteracion, round(a, 6), round(b, 6), round(c, 6), round(float(fa), 6), round(float(fb), 6), round(float(fc), 6), round(error, 6)))

        if iteracion > 20:
            break
```

Comment: ¿ y el problema que tienes? Por favor, debes poner lo que has hecho y en que parte tienes el problema. Así como lo has redactado hace pensar que quieres que te hagan la tarea y no creo que eso sea.

Comment: No es eso, es solo que no se muy bien como usar el foro

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Hola Darwin, podrías mostrarnos como estás importando los módulos?.

Comment: Hola Marce, los modulos son estos: import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from sympy import *
from tkinter import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (parse_expr, standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application)